# Are there certain characters that should not be saved to SharedPreferences or need to be escaped in some way?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Since SharedPreferences are saved as XML I wonder if there are certain characters (when putting a String) that will cause problems?

Which do we have to watch out for?

If so, does the SharedPreferences make any attempt to escape these characters or are we required to do some sanitation on our own?

Thanks!

Comment: Internally, SharedPreferences uses android.internal.util.XmlUtils - for String values it should be fine unless you intend to cram binary junk into the XML.